# Matplotlib basemap: offline map

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Hello when I use basemap with the max resolution (resolution='f'), it takes a lot of time to plot it.

For my project I have to use this resolution, but because the program have to be used by users, I want it as fast as possible.

Does it happen because it download the map from some online repository?

Is there a way to download the map I need and plot it offline?

This is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lon_min = -10.5
lon_max = 2.0
lat_min = 50.0
lat_max = 59.7

coastlinesMap = Basemap(suppress_ticks=False, projection='cyl',
                        llcrnrlat=lat_min, urcrnrlat=lat_max,
                        llcrnrlon=lon_min, urcrnrlon=lon_max,
                        resolution='f')

n = 100
x = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, n)
y = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, n)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z[i, j] = x[i] + y[j]

fig = plt.figure("test")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cf = ax.contourf(lon, lat, z, cmap="jet")
ax.set_xlabel("lon")
ax.set_ylabel("lat")
ax.add_collection(coastlinesMap.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
coastlinesMap.fillcontinents(color="green")
fig.colorbar(cf)

plt.show()
```

**Edit**

I just want to clarify that when the plot is shown, I can zoom or pan etc and the changes are fast, it's when `coastlineMap` is generated that is slow.

Comment: "f" means "fine", this is the finest resolution you can get and it indeed takes considerable time to draw. See also https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/252

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the answer! I will check that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and looking around I solved my problem using cPickle.

I report the solution below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import time
from six.moves import cPickle

lon_min = -10.5
lon_max = 2.0
lat_min = 50.0
lat_max = 59.7

t1 = time.clock()
coastlinesMap = Basemap(suppress_ticks=False, projection='cyl',
                        llcrnrlat=lat_min, urcrnrlat=lat_max,
                        llcrnrlon=lon_min, urcrnrlon=lon_max,
                        resolution='f')
print(time.clock()-t1,' secs to create original Basemap instance')
cPickle.dump(coastlinesMap, open('UKmap.pickle', 'wb'), -1)

n = 100
x = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, n)
y = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, n)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z[i, j] = x[i] + y[j]

fig = plt.figure("test")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cf = ax.contourf(lon, lat, z, cmap="jet")
ax.set_xlabel("lon")
ax.set_ylabel("lat")
ax.add_collection(coastlinesMap.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
coastlinesMap.fillcontinents(color="green")
fig.colorbar(cf)

t1 = time.clock()
m2 = cPickle.load(open('UKmap.pickle','rb'))

fig = plt.figure("test")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel("lon")
ax.set_ylabel("lat")
ax.add_collection(m2.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
m2.drawcountries()
print(time.clock()-t1,' secs to plot using using a pickled Basemap instance')

plt.show()
```